# How do I set MaxConnsPerHost on http2 transport in GoLang

Tags: go, http2, http-1.1, go-http

I'm trying to force GoLang to use HTTP2 and so have done the following:

```
transport := &http2.Transport{}
client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}
```

But I also need to set MaxConnsPerHost and MaxIdleConns, which I'm not able to. I know I can set them in HTTP1 as follows:

```
transport := &http.Transport{
    MaxIdleConns: 0,
    MaxIdleConnsPerHost: 1000,
}
httpClient := &http.Client{Transport: transport}
```

How can I achieve the same for HTTP2?

Comment: The whole point of HTTP2 is to send all requests and responses concurrently over a single connection, so MaxConnsPerHost doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here: As Peter pointed out, this would not apply to HTTP2.